# combobox or? is this even possible?

Tags: calculator

using windows form in visual studio ....ok so i am creating a sales tax calculator. I need to enter the state and the sales tax for the state and on a click event display the total amount in a textbox. i want to use only one dropdown instead of seperating out to two boxes(one for state and one for tax)

so if the combobox looked like this:

alabama 4% 
alaska 5% 
wisconsin 5.5%...and so on down the list of states

how can i click on one of the states that includes the tax shown in the dropdown and use just the percentage to run the calculation based on the item amount inputted.

c#calculator

Answer (score 0):

There are Quite a few ways you could do this and here is one. You could use a variable to store 
the part of the string on combo box i.e. { alabama 4% } the 4 would be what you want to get store 
it in a double, then make a switch statement that checks what state text is in the combo box and
pass that into the switch and if it is alabama then make the tax variable be 4.0;

```js
var tax;

switch(comboboxText)
{
  case alabama:
    tax = 4.0;
    break;
    case pennsylviana:
    tax = 5.5;
    break;
    //and so forth
}
```

then just append tax onto the end of your combobox string.